# Title missing and Pages not displayed properly in mn2e bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

@article entries in my `.bib` file are not being displayed properly in the .pdf generated. The 'title' goes missing and only the first entry of the pages get displayed. I am using `mn2e` bibliography style in `\documentclass [12pt,a4]{book}`. Below is an example `.bib` file entry and the output in `.pdf`

```
@article{langhorne,
title={Motor recovery after stroke: a systematic review},
author={P Langhorne and F Coupar and A Pollock},
journal="Lancet neurology",
volume={8},
number={8},
pages={741-754},
year={2009} }
```

Output:

> Langhorne P., Coupar F., Pollock A., 2009, Lancet neurology, 8, 741

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the bst file from here: http://www.mpe.mpg.de/~williams/mn2ebst/

Related to this link the entry type `@article` doesn't support a title. So the output for `mn2e` is correct.

However as recommended by the website above you should use `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{langhorne,
 title={Motor recovery after stroke: a systematic review},
 author={P Langhorne and F Coupar and A Pollock},
 journal="Lancet neurology",
 volume={8},
 number={8},
 pages={741-754},
 year={2009} 
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{langhorne}

\bibliographystyle{mn2e}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```